# insert the last 3 visits for each member

Tags: php, mysqli

i'm designing a Gym Administration System, each member has a unique number stored in a database, each member should type his number when he entered the gym to make sure if his subscription is ended or not, i already design that page, but i need that page to ( add the last 3 visits for each member ) ? how can i do it ?
i need to overwrite the last 3 visits everytime .
ID's 1,2 and 3 are the last visit for member

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test') or die('error' . mysqli_errno($con));

$query1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM checkin WHERE id = 1");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)){
?>
<div id="checkIn">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Check-In</td>
<td><?php echo $row['timeIn']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['dateIn']; } ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
$query2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM checkin WHERE id = 2");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)){
?>
<tr>
<td>Check-In</td>
<td><?php echo $row['timeIn']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['dateIn']; } ?></td>
</tr>
<?php 
$query3 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM checkin WHERE id = 3");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query3)){
?>
<tr>
<td>Check-In</td>
<td><?php echo $row['timeIn']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['dateIn']; } ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What exactly is id 1,2,3? The last visit id?

Comment: id 1,2,3 are the last visit @Daan

Comment: How do you know which user belongs to which checkin?

Comment: it's just for test, i only need to know how to insert the last 3 visits and overwrite them. @Daan

Comment: Does this count for all users or the logged in user?

Comment: @user3603620: are you want to show the each user's last 3 visits or the last 3 user visit?

Comment: @VishalSharma each user last 3 visits

Comment: @Daan all user's have an ID, when user come to sign up he will get a unique number, this number used for check if his subscription ended or not

Answer (score 1):

First create a query to fetch all users than loop through them.

```
$userQuery = $con->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM users");
$userQuery->execute();
$users = mysqli_fetch_array(userQuery);

foreach($users as $user) {
     $visitedQuery = $con->prepare("SELECT timeIn, dateIn FROM checkin WHERE user_id = ?  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3");
     $visitedQuery->execute(array($user['user_id']));

     $lastCheckIn = mysqli_fetch_array($visitedQuery);
     foreach($lastCheckIn as $lastCheck) {
         echo $lastCheckIn['timeIn']." ".$lastCheckIn['dateIn'];
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that each user have unique number.
For example:- User **A** have **123456** unique number.

In **Header.php** check the condition that user login or not. like:-

```
if($isset($_SESSION['user_login'])) //you can set your condition here according to your code
{
  // first create a new table where user's visit will save.
  // Say user database table name is USER_LOGS.which have 3 column.
  // ID,User_unique_id,viewpage 
  $query1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Id,viewpage  FROM USER_LOGS WHERE User_unique_id = 12345 ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 0"); // that will give you the user's last log. 
 $total_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query1);
 $current_page = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
 if($total_rows > 0)
 {

   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query1);
   if($row['viewpage'] != $current_page)
   {
     mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO USER_LOGS (Id,User_unique_id,viewpage)
     VALUES ('','123456','".$current_page."')");
   }
 }
 else
 {
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO USER_LOGS (Id,User_unique_id,viewpage)
    VALUES ('','123456','".$current_page."')");
 }
}
```

The above code is for inert the user log into the database now you can fetch the last three visit by using this query.

```
 mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Id,viewpage  FROM USER_LOGS WHERE User_unique_id = 12345 ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 0,3");
```